# How to cancel/hide window.alert immediately or after a period of time?

Tags: javascript, window, alert

Excuse me,
Does anyone know a way to cancel window.alert immediately or after a specific period of time,
Like,
Pop and Cancel

Comment: Pretty sure once alert() is called the user has to deal with it. Your best bet for something like that would be to create your own HTML alert box (high z-index, fixed position off screen or display:none} that you bring into view using javascript. Timing that should be no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible with the native `alert()`. Use a custom modal dialog (basically, make a `<div>` appear on top of the page - there's plenty of plug-ins to help with that if you don't want to code it yourself), as this will give you the freedom you need.